# Android Javascript interface function not works in ajax callback

Tags: javascript, android

I hava webView application in Android. I have defined the javascript interface `myapp` and I can successfully call it from webpage. I am testing the interface in an ajax function but when I call the functions in ajax success callback, nothing happens:

My Javascript codes in webpage:

```
    function notif(t,v){
        try {
             myapp.Logit("start"); // I can see this message in Logcat
        }catch(err){}

       $.ajax({
            method:"post",
            url:"test.asp",
            data:{t:t,v:v},
            success:function(data){
                 alert("done");   // Alert works in webpage
                  try {
                       myapp.Logit("finish");  // Nothing happens in Logcat
                  }catch(err){}
                }
            })
        }
```

And this is the simple function in Android app to log events in logcat:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void Logit(String message){
    Log.i("message:",message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you injecting the Java object into this WebView?

Please make sure that the you are injecting the Java object into the WebView as below. Without that you won't be able to access the Java objects's method in WebView

> webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyApp(), "MyApp");

It will also help to see if you are getting any error in the debug console. [Article on how to setup the remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews)

below is the sample working code. Hope this helps.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE))
            { WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true); }
        }
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                System.out.println("Web View loaded");
            }
        });

        Button loadBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.load_button);
        loadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String unencodedHtml =
                        "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
                                "<html>\n" +
                                "   <head>\n" +
                                "      <script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js\"></script>\n" +
                                "      <script>\n" +
                                "         $(document).ready(function(){\n" +
                                "           $(\"button\").click(function(){\n" +
                                "             $.ajax({\n" +
                                "             method:\"get\",\n" +
                                "             url: \"https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts\", \n" +
                                "             success: function(result){\n" +
                                "              alert(\"done\");   \n" +
                                "                           try {\n" +
                                "                                MyApp.Logit(\"finish\");  // Nothing happens in Logcat\n" +
                                "                           }catch(err){}\n" +
                                "             }});\n" +
                                "           });\n" +
                                "         });\n" +
                                "      </script>\n" +
                                "   </head>\n" +
                                "   <body>\n" +
                                "      <button>Get External Content</button>\n" +
                                "   </body>\n" +
                                "</html>";
                String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(unencodedHtml.getBytes(),
                        Base64.NO_PADDING);
                myWebView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64");
            }
        });
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyApp(), "MyApp");

    }
}

class MyApp
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void Logit(String message){
        Log.i("message:",message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have defined the interface similar to your codes and as I mentioned , Calling   `myapp.Logit("start")` works in main function. But calling again in callback function is not working. The only difference is that my html file is on the server and I load it in webView.

Comment: Is the POST call successful ?
Please check in the WebView debug console for any error message and try to invoke the `MyApp.Logit("finish")` directly from the WebView debug console and see what happens.